# How do you update a thumbnailPhoto in Active Directory using NodeJS and ldapjs?

Tags: node.js, active-directory, ldap, ldapjs, octetstring

I'm new to working with Active Directory in general. I'm trying to update the `thumbnailPhoto` attribute using `ldapjs` [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ldapjs) I have my code setup to be able to update attributes in general and it works well.

**I get my user like so:**

```
const customeParser = function(entry, raw, callback){ if (raw.hasOwnProperty("thumbnailPhoto")){ entry.thumbnailPhoto = raw.thumbnailPhoto; } callback(entry) }

find(filter, cb) {
        const client = ldap.createClient(this.ldapOptions)

        client.on('error', err => {
            console.error(err.message)
        })

        //Serach for users
        client.bind(
            this.options.dn,
            this.options.password,
            (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error((new Date).toUTCString(), 'Initial Bind Error', err)
                    client.unbind(() => {
                        client.destroy()
                        cb(err)
                    })
                } else {
                    client.search(
                        'DC=foo,DC=local', {
                        scope: 'sub',
                        attributes: [
                            'distinguishedName',
                            'name',
                            'sn',
                            'givenName',
                            'mail',
                            'sAMAccountName',
                            'telephoneNumber',
                            'thumbnailPhoto', 
                            // 'photoURL', 
                            // 'profileImage',
                            'extensionAttribute1',
                            'msExchExtensionCustomAttribute1'

                        ],
                        entryParser: customeParser,
                        filter: `${filter}`
                    },
                        (err, ee) => {


                            if (err) {
                                console.log((new Date).toUTCString(), 'SEARCH RESULT', err)
                                client.unbind(() => {
                                    client.destroy()
                                    cb(err)
                                })
                            }
                            ee.on('searchEntry', (entry) => {
                                ee.on('end', () => {
                                    client.unbind(() => {
                                        client.destroy()
                                        cb(null, entry.object)
                                    })
                                })
                            });
                        });
                }
            });
    }
```

**I call my `modifyUser` method from my LDAP class like so:**

```
let changes = {
  thumbnailPhoto: 'http://<ip>:<port>/img/photo.jpg'
}

ad.modifyUser(user.dn, changes, function (err, mod) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        return;
      }

      if (!mod) {
        console.log('Search: ' + mod + ' not found.');
      } else {
        console.log('MOD: ', JSON.stringify(mod));
      }
    })
```

**modifyUser:**

```
modifyUser(user, attributes, cb) {
        const client = ldap.createClient(this.ldapOptions)

        client.on('error', err => {
            console.error(err.message)
        })

        //Serach for users
        client.bind(
            this.options.dn,
            this.options.password,
            (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error((new Date).toUTCString(), 'Initial Bind Error', err)
                    client.unbind(() => {
                        client.destroy()
                        cb(err)
                    })
                } else {
                    var change = new ldap.Change({
                        operation: 'replace',
                        modification: attributes
                      });
                      console.log('CHANGE: ', attributes)
                      client.modify(user, change, function(err) {
                          if(err) console.error('ERROR: ', err);
                      },
                        (err, ee) => {
                            

                            if (err) {
                                console.log((new Date).toUTCString(), 'SEARCH RESULT', err)
                                client.unbind(() => {
                                    client.destroy()
                                    cb(err)
                                })
                            }
                            ee.on('searchEntry', (entry) => {
                                ee.on('end', () => {
                                    client.unbind(() => {
                                        client.destroy()
                                        cb(null, entry.object)
                                    })
                                })
                            });
                        });
                }
            });
    }
```

When I update the photo using my LDAP Tool it converts it to what i believe to be an octet or some sort of hex value. How do i mimic that in nodejs?

Am I on the right track? All other attributes get updated instantly using the code above, but the image fails to update...

Also is there a way to update multiple attributes at once? I get the error that only one attribute can be modified at a time.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Im trying to create a buffer and that doesn't seem to be working...the base64 string is too long... Anyone?

Comment: I don't know NodeJS very well, but `thumbnailPhoto` is just a byte array of the image file. It's not stored as base64.

Comment: Thanks @GabrielLuci I'll try to research how to convert an image to a byte array...

Comment: when i convert it to a byte array i get the following error: `ERROR:  LDAPError [ConstraintViolationError]: 00002082: AtrErr: DSID-031518F9, #1:
        0: 00002082: DSID-031518F9, problem 1005 (CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE), data 0, Att 160023 (thumbnailPhoto):len 1209421`

Comment: have you tried using toString method described here? https://github.com/ldapjs/node-ldapjs/pull/383